# How can I delete a row from an Oracle database in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlcommand

I have a problem when I want to delete an entire row based on `id_curse`. This is my code and this is my error I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

Additional information:

> External component has thrown an exception.

Can you help me to fix the problem? I think the code from the SQL-command is not good for this.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(provider);
    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand();

    conn.Open();
    cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(" DELETE * from CURSE  WHERE ID_CURSA  = '" +   textBox1.Text + "'", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Your code is highly insecure! Please read up on SQL injection & how to protect against it.

Comment: Whats the innerexception?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DELETE syntax is the following

```
DELETE   from CURSE  WHERE ID_CURSA  = xxxxx
       ^ no * here
```

But you should use parameterized queries not string concatenations. The string concatenation leads to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and parsing problems (string with quotes, decimals and dates not recognized)

```
string cmdText = "DELETE from CURSE WHERE ID_CURSA  = :ID"
using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(provider))
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdText, conn))
{
     conn.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", textBox1.Text);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As a side note, are you sure that the ID_CURSA is a text database field? (You are putting quotes around the value so I assume that is a text field)